# Basemap returning very large values

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Anybody know why the following snippet returns such large values for the projection of (47.4425433, -121.4424629) but not for (48,16)?

```
>>> from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
>>> m = Basemap(width=8000000,height=7000000,resolution='l',projection='aea',lat_1=46.,lat_2=48,lon_0=-121,lat_0=47)
>>> m(48,16)
(11720940.792536959, 14566938.248311447)
>>> m(47.4425433, -121.4424629)
(1e+30, 1e+30)
```

Shouldn't the equal area projection be centered on the latter point?

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake. The `Basemap` class requires coordinates to be passed in as (lon, lat) pairs when performing transformations. Obviously a latitude of -121.44 doesn't exist, ergo error.